# Django python: Using DateInput --Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, django, django-forms, datefield, django-widget

I'm trying to use DateInput, but I get the following error
`Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found` here `{{ form.incident_date_time_reported|add_class:"form-control"}}` (line 52)

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
import datetime
from functools import partial
DateInput = partial(forms.DateInput, {'class': 'datepicker'})

class IncidentForm(forms.Form):

    incident_date_time_reported = forms.DateField(initial=datetime.date, required=False, widget=forms.DateInput)

    def search(self):

        # cleaning the data
        incident_date_time_reported = self.cleaned_data.get('incident_date_time_reported')

        query = Incident.objects.all()

        if incident_date_time_reported is not None:
            query = query.filter(incident_date_time_reported=incident_date_time_reported)


        return(query)
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container-fluid">

    <!-----INPUT FORM------------------->
    <form action="{% url 'incidents:index' %}" method="GET">

        <div class="row">                       
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>Date Incident Reported</label><br>
                {{ form.incident_date_time_reported|add_class:"form-control"}}
                {{ form.incident_date_time_reported.errors }}
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label>------</label>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Search</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div><!-----END OF BOOTSTAP CONTAINER FLUID----->
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[datetime.date](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today) is incorrectly used. It's a function with all the arguments required.

If you are attempting to initially populate with the current day, you should use `datetime.date.today()`.

Answer (score -4):

I resolved it delete **migrations** folder in my project